# easyreview package : setreviewsoff not working

Tags: positioning, article, code-review

I have been working on a personal template for preparing my papers in case some journal don't have one.
In the way, I found the **easyReview package** and the commands `\setreviewsoff` or `\setreviewson` quite useful.

However, when preparing my document, the command `\setreviewsoff` doesn't work for me; even in a minimal file (as recommended in the [User’s Guide](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/easyreview/doc/easyReview.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easyReview}

%\setreviewson 
\setreviewsoff

\begin{document}

\comment{The text to comment}{the comment}

\end{document}
```

Have any of you had the same problem? Maybe I'm not placing the command in the correct place? I have already tried after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Have you tried placing the command *after* the `\begin{document}`?

Comment: **also**: looking at the source of `easyReview` https://github.com/jmamatos/easyReview/blob/master/texmf/tex/latex/easyReview/easyReview.sty the `\highlight` and `\comment` commands are designed to **not** obey the `\setreviewson/off` requests.

Comment: @WillieWong, Yes... same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I don't get the rationale behind the coding of `easyReview`. Some of its macros, including `\comment`, are insentitive to the switches `\setreviewson`/`\setreviewsoff`. For example, `\comment` is defined as

```
\newcommand{\comment}[2]{\highlight{#1}\todo[inline]{#2}}
```

and it's a mystery to me how the documentation can obtain the claimed output.

Considering that the code of `easyReview` is roughly a dozen lines you could consider making your own version. Alternatively here is a quick fix:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{easyReview}
\renewcommand{\comment}[2]{\ifistoreview\highlight{#1}\todo[inline]{#2}\else#1\fi}

\begin{document}
The \comment{text}{the comment} to comment.

\setreviewsoff
The \comment{text}{the comment} to comment.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh you're right... Your solution may work for now. Thank you  @campa !

Comment: I'm trying to understand your solution (just for knowing). What is '\ifisto' for? I don't get how latex know about the *on/off* stuff.
Thank you, I'm kind of newby.

Comment: @VladimirHeredia The package defines a boolean `\ifistoreview`, the macro `\setreviewson` sets it to true, ans `\setreviewsoff` to false.